# Using BullMQ with NestJs, is it possible to use a config variable as part of a Job name?

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs, bullmq

I'm trying to use an environment variable value in the nestjs/bull module's @Process() decorator, as follows. How should I provide the 'STAGE' variable as part of the job name?

```ts
import { Process, Processor } from '@nestjs/bull';
import { Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { Job } from 'bull';

@Processor('main')
export class MqListener {

  constructor(
    @Inject(ConfigService) private configService: ConfigService<SuperRootConfig>,
  ) { }

  // The reference to configService is not actually allowed here:
  @Process(`testjobs:${this.configService.get('STAGE')}`)
  
  handleTestMessage(job: Job) {
    console.log("Message received: ", job.data)
  }
}
```

EDITED with answers (below) from Micael and Jay:

Micael Levi answered the initial question: You can't use the NestJS ConfigModule to get your config into a memory variable. However, running dotenv.config() in your bootstrap function will not work either; you get undefined values for the memory variables if you try to access them from within a Method Decorator. To resolve this, Jay McDoniel points out that you have to import the file before you import AppModule. So this works:

```ts
// main.ts
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
require('dotenv').config()
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4500);
}
bootstrap();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `this` on that context due to how [decorator evaluation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorator-evaluation) works. At that time, there's no instance created for `MqListener` class, thus, using `this.configService` doens't make sense.

You'll need to access `process.env.` directly. And so will call `dotenv` (or what lib that read & parses your dot env file) in that file.

Comment: Thx. I have tried accessing process.env directly but the value is undefined when it is called. In addition to being loaded through ConfigService (not useful it seems), I also tried loading it with dotenv.config() in main.ts, upon startup, just prior to app.listen(). The value is still undefined: @Process(`${process.env.STAGE}`) is passed undefined. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you call `dotenv.config()` **before** importing the `app.module` file? Order is important here